# use html form value inserted into php file for csv export

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following form I want to be able to set the invoice number that will be the starting point used in my php file that I have made to export orders to csv:

```
<form action="QB_EXPORT.php" method="post">

    <div class="add-to-cart-quantity">

        <label class="quantity-label" >invoice starting number</label><br/>
        <input type="number" min="1" value="25200" name="invoice_number" style="width:225px; height:21px;  text-align:center; border:2px solid rgb(224, 224, 224); padding:10px; ">

    </div>
    <br/><br/>
<div id="cartbutt">


    <div class="shop-card">
        <button name="submit" class="btn addToCartButton" style="float:none;">EXPORT INVOICES<span class="bg"></span></button>
    </div>



</div>

    </form>
```

I want to use the value from the input number "invoice_number" as the starting value in my php file QB_EXPORT.php

Is there a way to use it in the php file? THe only way I can think of is to create a database entry for the value and then pull it from the database in the QB_EXPORT.php file but I was just curious if there is a way to avoid having to store it in the database which now that I am typing it out I am realizing won't be that hard.

Comment: Do you mean like $_POST?

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved in the comments, but for completeness I figured I should make a formal answer in case other people find this and can't read the comments.

You have the option of using `$_POST` like so:

```
$name = $_POST["invoice_number"];
```